# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..10: 11

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I'm building an app that integrated a deep learning model, this is the example input and output:
input = [[30, 143, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]]
output = [[0.2993126   0.63993865   0.06074876]]

this is my code in flutter, and I don't know why it keeps showing the error "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..10: 11"

```
Future<void> model() async {
    final interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset('tflite/delivery_mode.tflite');

    var input = [
      [int.parse(age), int.parse(heig), pos, plac, hyper, amn, diab]
    ];
    print(input);

    var output = List.filled(3, 0).reshape([1, 3]);
    print(output);
    interpreter.run(input, output);
    print(output);
  }
```

I have imported tflite and tflite_flutter but still can't solve this issue.

Comment: As per error its says that you are trying to access 12 number of position where your arry of value 11 from 0..to 10.